# codesniffer command not being recognized after several installs and upgrades

Tags: php, apache, pear, phpcodesniffer

I've tried to install codesniffer using pear but my mac is not recognizing the phpcs command.

## pear config

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/local/pear/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/local/pear/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/local/pear/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /private/tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/local/pear/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/local/pear/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /opt/local/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini-development
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/local/pear/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/local/pear/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /opt/local/etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/anthonygordon/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /opt/local/etc/pear.conf
```

i checked php_bin and the php executable is there.

when i run phpcs i get `command not found`

Ive tried to upgrade pear, uninstall reinstall code sniffer, everything. when i run installs list i get

## Pear List

```
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.10  stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
PHP_CodeSniffer  1.4.0   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

Answer (score 8):

The phpcs script should be inside the `bin_dir`, so at `/usr/local/pear/bin/phpcs` so just make sure that file exists first. If not, something went wrong with the install.

See if you can run it directly: `php /usr/local/pear/bin/phpcs -?`

If that outputs the PHPCS help, then PHPCS is installed correctly and the problem is probably your $PATH. Run `echo $PATH` and make sure `/usr/local/pear/bin` is shown in there. If not, you can modify your path settings, or you can configure PEAR to put executable scripts somewhere else.

For example, your $PATH may already include `/usr/local/bin` (as my Mac does), so you could change the `bin_dir`to that:

```
pear uninstall php_codesniffer
pear config-set bin_dir /usr/local/bin
pear install php_codesniffer
```

And now try the `phpcs` command again.

Comment: Your solution worked half way for me. I can atleast see some errors that i could fix, Thanks for the steps